# How do I SSH access to a webpage hosted on a Docker container on a remote computer?

Tags: docker, port, ssh-tunnel

I have a webpage hosted on `0.0.0.0:5555` in a Docker container on a remote computer (through some IP address, let's say `123.4.5.6`), which listens to external connections on port `8000`.

How do I access to this webpage on my local machine through port `5555`?

What I have so far is:

- on my local machine : `ssh -p 8000 -L 5555:0.0.0.0:5555 user@123.4.5.6`
- on the remote machine :
  `docker run -it --rm -p 5555:5555 docker_src`

However, it says the bind for `0.0.0.0:5555` failed because the port is already allocated.

How should I connect to the remote page hosted on `0.0.0.0:5555`

Comment: @StephenC, a Python script running in the docker container starts a web server `0.0.0.0:5555/web`, and the docker container is on a remote machine, so essentially I would like to connect to this web server from my local desktop.

Comment: @StephenC, you can use ssh to port-forward aka ssh tunnelling to connect to an http service. You need to connect on the forwarded port on your system.

Comment: But that is not doing SSH access to a web page ... which is what the Question asks.  That is setting up an SSH tunnel so that you can use a browser / HTTP client to access the web page.  You are using HTTP to access the web page.

Answer (score 0):

If the run command fails because port 5555 is already taken, you need to stop what is listening on this port or use a different port when you publish the container port.

```sh
docker run -it --rm --publish 5556:5555 docker_src
```

Then you also need to use 5556 in your tunnel command.

Comment: Thanks! But what about if I need to do a two-layered port-forwarding? I would need to do port-forwarding from the docker container to the remote computer, and then another port-forwarding from the remote to the local computer.

Comment: @NicTam, what do you mean two layered port forwarding? You publish the port with docker run and that's it. You don't use ssh to port forward the container's port to the remote host. It's done via iptables, under the hood.

Comment: The server started at `0.0.0.0:5555` in the docker (which is on the remote machine). I would like to access the server on my local machine, so I imagine you would have to do some sort of port forwarding twice.

Comment: @NicTam, that is what the `-p` or long `--publish` flag is for. As I said, its actually done via iptables if you care about the implementation details.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Comment: Once you have published the port, its bound on the remote host. So you need only tunnel to the bound port you have published with -p.

Comment: As I was told (by the system administrator), the `-p` flag was to connect to the port where the server is listening. I can only connect to the remote computer through the port specified after the `-p` flag.

On another note, I have tried the above, and somehow when I typed in `localhost:8080`, it says connection reset. Any thoughts on why would that be?

Comment: @NicTam, have you run the container and published its port on 5556 before you tried to open the tunnel?

Comment: Or it is because the ssh server is listening on port 8000 for some reason, which may explain the -p flag on the ssh command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242645/discussion-between-nictam-and-the-fool).